# How to get NT account in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can anybody tell me how to get NT account's name using Silverlight?
I know it easy to get a NT account in asp.net. 
But my Silverlight website is hosted in a html page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put - you don't. There is no concept of authentication until you call out to a web service that needs it, at that point identity will flow to the service. So you could have a service which returns the user name it's called with.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a spammer's dream come true. MYDOMAIN\johndoe would give him enough info to come up with a valid email address of johndo@mydomain.com. So no, Silverlight won't let you access that information from a HTML-hosted application.

What you can do however, assuming your application is hosted on a page in the local intranet zone, is access the user name on the server and then pass it to the Silverlight application through the [InitParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.startupeventargs.initparams%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

Comment: Hello Josh, I know how to use "initParams". But it is hard to get account in default.html.I add <param name="initParams"..>. But it does not work in default.html                                                          <param name="initParams" value="UserAccount=<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>" />

Comment: You'll need to rename to .aspx since .html won't execute on the server.